# How to auto fill credit card details in braintree?

Tags: ios, credit-card, braintree

***auto fill credit card details.***

> credit card details store in signup and when i use payment getaway using braintree then credit card details auto fill up in textfield.

Answer (score 0):

You can save creditcard details through Braintree by using Customer IDs. When paying, Braintree will show saved payment methods for the user.

**Example**:

[image]

**Explanation**:
https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/customers/ruby

Answer (score 0):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

As @Robski18 mentioned, you can create a customer with an [associated payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/customers/ruby#create-with-payment-method). Then, when you use `Braintree::Transaction.sale()` to create a transaction, you can pass in a `customer_id` to use that customer’s [default payment method](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/transactions/ruby#sale).

Alternatively, if you don’t have a payment method when the customer gets created, you can save that customer’s payment method in the Vault after a successful transaction by [setting the `store_in_vault_on_success` option to true](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/transaction/sale/ruby#storing-in-vault).

When you [set up your client](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/hello-client/ios/v4) using a [client token generated with a customer ID](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/client-token/generate/ruby), the Drop-in UI will display the customer's stored payment method options.

If you have further questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).